# How to read mail and insert into database using Mule?

Tags: java, email, mule, jakarta-mail

I have to create an application in Mule which will read the mail from a store and save it's details in a database. I know how to insert the data into the database but I am unable to find any solution about the mail. How do I read the mail and parse it in Mule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answers are correct, however rather than hand rolling your own solution you might be better off using the [IMAP connector](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/IMAP+Transport+Reference)

A sample could be like the below

```
<flow name="incoming-orders">
        <imaps:inbound-endpoint user="${mail.user}" password="${mail.password}" host="${mail.host}" 
                     port="${mail.port}"/>
     <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
     </flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Mule, but assuming you can write plain old Java code in Mule, you can use the [JavaMail API](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) to read and parse email messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Mule with your own components, even Spring components should work.

```
<flow name="SomeFlow">
  <!-- Some inbound endpoint -->

  <component class="com.my.class.MyComponent"/>
</flow> 

public class MyComponent implements Callable {

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext muleEventContext) throws Exception {
        //add your code here
    }
}
```

Also, you can add spring config in the mule xml.

```
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

<!--...-->

<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.stuff" />
<bean class="com.my.spring.Component" />
```